# Django CRUD app using only bare SQL (no ORM at all)?

Tags: django

What would one need to do to avoid ORMs entirely in a Django "CRUD" app, and communicate with the DB strictly using "bare" SQL?  Is it even possible?  If so, what would one put in `settings.py` to enable this?

Comment: but why would you want to do that ?

Comment: @karthikr: your question implies either that you think I'm a rank beginner, or that you're spoiling for a fight.  Well, I'll just say that I've been writing software for a long time...

Comment: Well.. I dont give a damn for what your level of experience is. I just wanted to konw why you would want to bypass the ORM to help you better.

Comment: If you don't give a damn about my level of experience, then you have no excuse for asking a question that can *only* lead to polemic.

Comment: Ok buddy.. Relax !! dont stress.